# Likert scale sample size calculation

Tags: scale, mean, spss

I want to know how to calculate the sample size for measureing a significant difference between 2 groupos o a likert scale? How do I group my variables? In SPSS please.

Answer (score 0):

so are you asking how to determine what the sample size is given the data you have, or what sample size is necessary to detect a significant difference?

Comment: I am asking how to determine what the sample size is given the data I have